# The variable I initialised as 0 randomly turns into a -1?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, quicksort, stdvector

I am trying to make vector based QuickSort implementation. However I ran into an out of range exception and I cannot figure out whats wrong with my code.

```
void myQuicksort(std::vector<int>& values, int first, int last);

int largest(std::vector<int>& values)
{
    //using Quicksort
    int first = 0;
    int last = values.size() - 1;
    myQuicksort(values, first, last);
    return values[last-1];
    
}

void myQuicksort(std::vector<int>& values, int first, int last)
{
    int cnt1, cnt2, pivot, Temporary;
    if (first < last)
    {
        pivot = first;
        cnt1 = first;
        cnt2 = last;
        while (cnt1 < cnt2)
        {
            while (values[cnt1] <= values[pivot] && (cnt1 < last))
            {
                cnt1++;
            }
            while (values[cnt2] > values[pivot])
            {
                cnt2--;
            }
            if (cnt1 < cnt2)
            {
                Temporary = values[pivot];
            }
        }
        Temporary = values[pivot];
        values[pivot] = values[cnt2];
        values[cnt2] = Temporary;
        myQuicksort(values, first, cnt2 - 1);
        myQuicksort(values, cnt2 - 1, last);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> signature = { 0,21,34,55,8,13,1,1,2,3,5 };
    std::cout << largest(signature)<<std::endl; 
}
```

I used the debugger to find the "first" variable got reassigned as a -1. There are no clues as to why this happened. This lead to an out of range exception.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more specific. There are two variables with the name `first` in your program (one in the function `largest` and one in the function `myQuicksort`).

Comment: Can you tell us which line caused the variable `first` to unexpectedly receive a new value? You can run your code line by line in a debugger while monitoring the value of the variable, in order to determine this.

Comment: Replace `[...]` with `.at(...)` to see where the out of range error occurs.

Comment: If you use `g++` or `clang++` add `-fsanitize=address` when compiling and it'll tell you the exact line causing the problem. Hint: Right before `while (values[cnt1] <= values[pivot] && (cnt1 < last))` add this line: `std::cout << cnt1 << ' ' << pivot << ' ' << last << std::endl;`. It'll show `0 0 10` for the first iteration and `-1 -1 10` for the second. --== **Boom** ==--

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: The problem is: `myQuicksort(values, cnt2 - 1, last);`. The value of `cnt2` is `0`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tq0dRZdIhV4g2JII You would find it stepping line by line through your code with your debugger.

Comment: I tried moving the pivot to the last value and that didnt work either

Comment: @jkengineeringworkvideos Don't just randomly change things. Do you know how to use a debugger? If you don't, add debug printouts like the one I suggested above. Add them everywhere so you can follow what the values are and from there find out where it goes awry.

Comment: Is my assumption correct that you are trying to implement the [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme)?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes I am trying to implement that

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I edited the code I found here [link](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/02/quicksort-program-in-c/)

Comment: Why are you not swapping the two values in the `if (cnt1 < cnt2)` block. In the code you linked to, the values are swapped. In C++, you can either simply use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) or you can use a temporary variable.

Comment: Why are you writing `myQuicksort(values, cnt2 - 1, last);` instead of `myQuicksort(values, cnt2 + 1, last);`? The code you linked to uses the latter.

Comment: You should probably change `return values[last-1];` to `return values[last];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Thomas Sablik and Andreas Wenzel, the main problem is in the second call to myQuickSort() and it should be

```
std::swap(values[pivot], values[cnt2]);
myQuicksort(values, first, cnt2 - 1);
myQuicksort(values, cnt2 + 1, last);   // <-- passing cnt2 - 1 here discarded the pivot
```

because you just swapped `values[cnt2]` and `values[pivot]`, placing the pivot of this iteration at the correct place, ie `cnt2`.
Therefore the next iterations must avoid `cnt2` and run before and past it

Both these comparisons must be less than equal rather than just less than

```
// If only this comparison is <= the loop doesn't end
while (cnt1 <= cnt2)
{
    // If only this comparison is <= it doesn't sort correctly
    while (values[cnt1] <= values[pivot] && (cnt1 <= last))
```

Andreas Wenzel also noted that in the block under `if (cnt1 < cnt2)` the code doesn't actually do anything. To me it seems that you started writing the swap and just forgot to complete it :)
Anyway, this is a fixed version.

```
void myQuicksort(std::vector<int>& values, int first, int last)
{
    if (first >= last)
        return;

    int cnt1 = first;
    int cnt2 = last;
    int pivot = first;

    while (cnt1 <= cnt2)
    {
        while (values[cnt1] <= values[pivot] && (cnt1 <= cnt2)) // It just needs to go to cnt2, not last
            cnt1++;

        while (values[cnt2] > values[pivot])
            cnt2--;

        if (cnt1 < cnt2)
        {
        // Temporary = values[pivot]; had no effect
        // It is very likely that an IDE would have shown a warning due to static code analysis
            std::swap(values[cnt1], values[cnt2]);
            cnt1++;
            cnt2--;
        }
    }
    std::swap(values[pivot], values[cnt2]);
    myQuicksort(values, first, cnt2 - 1);
    myQuicksort(values, cnt2 + 1, last);  // <-- passing cnt2 - 1 here discarded the pivot
}
```

Like the other have already suggested, to develop algorithms a debugger is really useful, because you can go through your code step by step and inspect the variables.
Also, using an IDE with a static analyzer could help you identify the little mistakes as soon as you type them.

Comment: I did that and it lead to an infinite loop

Comment: @jkengineeringworkvideos: The reason for the infinite loop probably is the following: As I already pointed out in the comments section, you are not swapping the values in the `if (cnt1 < cnt2)` block. The line `Temporary = values[pivot];` in that `if` block effectively does nothing (Note: That statement also exists somewhere else in your program). In the code you linked to, there are 3 lines in that `if` block. If you want to use one line, you must use `std::swap`.

Comment: You're right, I implemented a correct version, but copied only the last segment

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the posted code. If you do `std::vector<int> signature = { 18,21,6,34,55,22,8,13,1,15,1,14,2,3,5 };`, then, after sorting, the number `22` will appear after `34`, which is incorrect.